# include script is not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script

i write a code.gs file whose two functions are

```
function menuItem2(){

 var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('firstFile').evaluate();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));

}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

i write a html page named it as firstFile

```
<?= include('bootstrap-picker'); ?>
<div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>
```

but the dialogue instead of including script tag its showing me script as text instead of including it what is the mistake that i am doing ??please guideline

[image]

Comment: I too am having the same problem with my include scripts working in a contained-script area. I've tried wrapping them using `<? ?>` and `<?!= ?>` and the output for both is exactly as you've shown above. I've just resorted to placing the `<style>` and `<script>` tags into the same html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<?= ?>` syntax will escape characters.
In this case, you should use `<?!= ?>` syntax.
It does not escape characters.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets